# Html Agility Pack Dll

Tags: c#, web-crawler, html-agility-pack

I have downloaded the HTML Agility pack but I don't know which one should I import .There are lots of folders and I don't know which one to import dll .
Folders:

```
    Net20
    Net40
    net40-client
    Net45
    sl3-wp
    sl4
    sl4-windowsphone71
    sl5
    winrt45
```

I tried importing winrt45 but am getting error when I use **doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes** (There is no reference ) 
I have tried

```
    using HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument;
    using HtmlAgilityPack;
```

but doesn't work

Comment: What .NET Framework version is your application being built in?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct assembly to reference strongly depends on your target framework.

> This release includes versions of Html Agility Pack for .NET 2.0 -
>   4.5, Silverlight 4-5, Windows Phone 7-7.1 and Windows 8 Metro.

*(Source: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/releases/view/90925)*

According to the quote above:

```
Directory             | Framework
----------------------+-------------------------------------------
Net20                 | .NET 2.0
Net40                 | .NET 4.0
net40-client          | .NET 4.0 Client Profile
Net45                 | .NET 4.5
sl3-wp                | Silverlight 3
sl4                   | Silverlight 4
sl4-windowsphone71    | Silverlight 4 used by Windows Phone 7.1+
sl5                   | Silverlight 5
winrt45               | Windows RT
```

**NuGet**

The preferred method of referencing HtmlAgilityPack is through **nuget**:
 http://nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack